# When cycle starts everything else is ignored

Tags: android

So what i was trying to write and kind of succeeded is stroboscope ( Flashlight flashing at some high frequency ). But the thing is that when I start it, it works, but when i press button again to turn it off, nothing happens.

Chunks of code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

// Some code for checking if flashlight availabe and listener for seekbar for getting frequncy

...

// My button listener (but1 - button)

but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (flashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnFlashOn();
            }
        }
    });
```

And now main big chunk of code, i dont think that i can skip any of this

```
private void getCamera() {
        if(cam == null) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open();
                params = cam.getParameters();
            } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera failed to open", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }   
    private void turnFlashOn() {
        if(!flashOn) {
            if(cam == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }else {
              if (freq == 0) {
                  camParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
              }


              else {
                  sr = new StroboRunner();
                  sr.freq = freq;
                  t = new Thread(sr);
                  t.start();
                  strob = true;
                  return ;
              }

            }

        }
    }

    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if(flashOn){
            if(cam == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            if(strob){
                sr.stopRunning = true;
                t = null;
                strob = false;
                return;
            }
             else camParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        cam.setParameters(camParams);
        cam.startPreview();

    }


     private class StroboRunner implements Runnable {

         int freq;
         boolean stopRunning = false;

         @Override
         public void run() {
             Camera.Parameters paramsOn = cam.getParameters();
             Camera.Parameters paramsOff = cam.getParameters();
             paramsOn.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             paramsOff.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             try {
                 while (!stopRunning) {
                    cam.setParameters(paramsOn);
                    cam.startPreview();

                    Thread.sleep(freq);

                    cam.setParameters(paramsOff);
                    cam.stopPreview();

                    Thread.sleep(freq);
                  }
                 }
             catch(Throwable t) {}
         }
     }
```

I'm not really advanced a lot, so I don't know like 20% of what i wrote, since it was half following one tutorial and half writing code of my own.

Comment: what does your `turnOffFlash()` method do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you set the `flashOn` like:

```
flashOn = true;
```

It's possible that you click the button and are getting `!flashOn` everytime.